# How to find duplicates across a mutli-dimensional array in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've found lots of questions regarding eliminating duplicates from arrays but I'm trying to identify them. Say I have a multi-dimensional array like

```
array = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,3,4]]
```

I want to return only the values that exist in all the arrays. Thus,

```
result = [3,4]
```

I know how to do it with only two arrays

```
array[0].filter(value => -1 !== array[1].indexOf(value)
```

However I need to do a similar thing with an n-number of arrays

Comment: You can use `flat` and then filter:  `const all_duplicates = array.flat().filter((item, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) !== index)`.  Then just use `new Set` to bring up repeated unique values:  `const duplicates = [...new Set(all_duplicates)]`

Answer (score 0):

Just take your answer between two arrays and generalize it:

```
result = array[0];
for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  result = getDups(result, array[i]); //getDups is your array[0].filter(value =>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over one of the items from the array, (for example the first one) and basically use `filter()` and `every()` to get the ones that existing in the rest.

```js
const array = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,3,4]]

const first = array[0];

const filteredArr = first.filter(item => array.slice(1).every(temp => temp.includes(item)));

console.log(filteredArr);
```